# moving horizontal background line when hovering other links in the same list

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, hover, jquery-animate

Would you mind to take a look at [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Autodealers/YFUsJ/)?

As you can see, I putted a horizontal line below an active list item anchor.
I want the horizontal line to be at the bottom** of an anchor, just like a border-bottom when hovering, not at where my cursor stands. Can anybody help me out?

Thank you in advanced!
With Kind Regards,
Jonathan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because you were using an `li` element for the line that it was stopping the mouseover of the `ul` and reversing the animation. Instead use a `div` inside a containing element, with a lower z-index to stop it intercepting the mouseover event.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">sub nav</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sub nav</a></li>
        <li><a href="# "class="active">sub nav</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sub nav</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Amended javascript:

```
var animation = $('<div>').css({
    'position': 'absolute',
    'height': active.outerHeight()-1,
    'width': active.outerWidth(),
    'marginTop': (active.parent().index() * active.outerHeight()),
    'borderBottom': '1px solid #000',
    'z-index': -10
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YFUsJ/14/)

Also, you need to make the `border-bottom` transparent on the `ul li a` elements for the line to show through them. You could use `margin-bottom: 1px` if you prefer.

Comment: You're my man Rory! Thanks for helping me out on this one, this is exactly what I wanted to archive.

Comment: No need to use a `div` element, it should also work using a `li` element with a lower z-index.

Comment: True, but having an `li` element out of document flow is not very semantic IMO.

Comment: Okay, here I have to agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve, but if it's just getting a line under the active `<li>` element then [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yJ9JM/) might do the job.

It uses your css to apply the underline, with some simplified jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul').mouseout(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }).

    $('ul > li').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply LordSauce! Next time I'll try to explain my question better. I think more in pictures then in words.. Rory got my question answered, see my selected answer above.

Comment: No worries! Glad someone was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the animated `li` has a higher z-index than the other list elements. And you need to remove the white border from the links.

Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YFUsJ/12/

CSS:

```
ul li {
    display: block;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    display: block;
    padding:5px;
    color: #555;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

Comment: Thnx Alex! This is what I wanted. But as Rory says, his way of putting a div element instead of a list item is more semantic.

Comment: Yes, I have to agree with you guys.